# MySQL Trigger cannot update table - getting ERROR 1442

Tags: mysql

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum
AFTER INSERT
ON news
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE news SET NEW.sum = (NEW.int_views + NEW.ext_views)/NEW.pageviews
```

It sums the `int_views` and `ext_views` column of a table and divides them by the total pageviews.

Whenever I try to add a new row to news, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000) at line 3: Can't update table 'news' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

The trigger seems pretty simple to me. Is there a reason why the trigger fails to run?

Comment: @jcho360, Sorry, I'm not seeing where to include a where condition. I want the trigger to execute on every row after it's inserted.

Comment: if that doesn't works let me know to try with the `WHERE news_id = NEW.news_id;` at the end

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The **symptom** is, that you are running an `UPDATE` (for all rows) inside a `INSERT` trigger - both modify the table, which is not allowed.

That said, if I guess the intention of your trigger correctly, you do not want to update **all** rows, but only the newly inserted row. You can achieve that easily with

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum
BEFORE INSERT
ON news
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.sum = (NEW.int_views + NEW.ext_views)/NEW.pageviews
```

Mind that this is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, as you want to change the row before it is written to the table.

Comment: same issues for me, just had to remove the UPDATE tlb part - thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you try to update/insert on the same table that cause trigger to fire do not use the common `sql` command like

```
-> UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = VALUE WHERE CONDITION_LIST;  
-> INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES("VALUE1","VALUE2");
```

This will not work. Only use set to assign the value of the column you update.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.COLUMN_NAME = "VALUE";
```

Comment: It was a sensible and reasonable response. It helped me resolve the error appropriately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar condition where I had to run two triggers:

1. UPDATE 3 fields on INSERTing a new ROW
2. UPDATE 3 fields on UPDATEing a ROW

After lot of efforts, I was finally able to write the TRIGGER in following way:

**FOR updating values on INSERT**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `INSERT_DISCOUNT_SERVICES` BEFORE INSERT ON `services`
FOR EACH ROW SET 
NEW.discount_5_rate = (NEW.ndis_rate*0.05),
NEW.discount_10_rate=(NEW.ndis_rate*0.10),
NEW.discount_15_rate=(NEW.ndis_rate*0.15)
```

Similarly

**FOR updating values on UPDATE**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_DISCOUNTS_SERVICES` BEFORE UPDATE ON `services`
FOR EACH ROW SET 
NEW.discount_5_rate = (NEW.ndis_rate*0.05), 
NEW.discount_10_rate=(NEW.ndis_rate*0.10),
NEW.discount_15_rate=(NEW.ndis_rate*0.15)
```