# create a trigger to for conditional update on same table

Tags: mysql

```
 delimiter //
 create trigger T1 before update on account
     for each row
        if NEW.balance <= 0 then
          update account set balance=OLD.balance;
       end if;
     //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

 delimiter ;
 update account set balance=-1 where id=101;
```

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'account' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses row level triggers, so the trigger is fired for each row that is being changed. Because of that there is no reason to update the target table, just assign the value:

```
create trigger T1 before update on account
 for each row
    if NEW.balance <= 0 then
      set new.balance = OLD.balance; -- this is the difference
   end if;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34aebb/1

---

Your update wouldn't have worked anyway because it was missing a `where` clause which means you would have updated the *entire* table just because a single row was changed.