# Got Error 1442 trying to trigger update

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I was trying to trigger an update of `chatroompost.view` from 1 to 0 when update happened and `chatroompost.likecount <= -5`

```
CREATE TRIGGER `chatroompost_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `chatroompost` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    IF (NEW.likecount <= -5) THEN
        UPDATE `chatroompost` SET NEW.`view`='0'  WHERE `chatroompost`.`idchatroompost` = OLD.`idchatroompost`;   
    END IF;  
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

The query:

```
UPDATE `chatroompost` SET likecount='-11' WHERE idchatroompost=1; SELECT *FROM chatroompost;
```

but I got

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'chatroompost' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I have tried to `REPLACE` all the `AFTER` to `BEFORE` but still got the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442

Comment: I was tring to trigger an update of chatroompost.view from 1 to 0 when update happend and chatroompost.likecount <=-5
but I got Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'chatroompost' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
I have tried to REPLACE all the AFTER to BEFORE but still got the same 1442.

Comment: Have you checked above link?

Comment: http://www.mysql-database-recovery.com/fix-error-1442.php

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: make it a BEFORE UPDATE ON trigger, and use NEW operator, it'll do the job.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS`chatroompost_AFTER_UPDATE` ; 
DELIMITER $$ 
use mydb $$

CREATE TRIGGER `chatroompost_AFTER_UPDATE` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `chatroompost` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    IF (NEW.likecount <= -5) THEN
        NEW.view='0';   
    END IF;  
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

**Cause**: You cannot update a table (chatroompost) where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate Error 1442:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'chatroompost' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```