# how to update a column instead of delete in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to change the column archive to 1, instead of deleting the row.

For example, I have a row with some attributes, the last one is "archive", which normally is to 0, and a delete sql is done, it must not delete the row, but juste change the attribute archive to 1.

I think that I have to use a trigger. I tried, but it don't work.

I done a trigger after delete, and I insert the line after the deletion.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `type`(`tId`,`archive`) VALUES (OLD.tId, 1);
END
```

Then I have the error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'type' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

Why do you first delete and insert afterwards the same data again?

Can you use a [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement like this?

```
UPDATE `type` SET `archive`=1 WHERE `tId` = OLD.tid;
```

Comment: You're right, but I have exactly the same error. http://puu.sh/lPiK9/bcc340bbf7.png

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442 
Summary: The symptom is, that you are running an UPDATE (for all rows) inside a INSERT trigger - both modify the table, which is not allowed.

Comment: Ok,  yes and no. I do this with a delete trigger. When a user want to delete  this row, this row must not to delete the row, but just update the archive attribute to 1. My idea was, to reinsert the line after deletion, because I can't stop the delete!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it means you already have the row existing so try try to `UPDATE` the row instead on `INSERT`

```
UPDATE table_name SET archive='1' WHERE tid=OLD.Tid;
```