# auto update sql column when another column is updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have two columns in sql table (*credits* and *badge*). I want when the credits are updated for the badge to change according to the credits new value.

for example when credits are < 100 I want badge to be 'beginner' and if credits become 200 I want badge to update to 'advanced' (just an example).

I tried **triggers** but they didn't work for some reason (MySQL Error #1442)

I'm using PhpMyAdmin
Trigger:

```
update users 
set badge = (CASE 
    WHEN credits < 50 
    THEN 1
    WHEN credits >= 50 
    THEN 2
    WHEN credits >= 100 
    THEN 3
    WHEN credits >= 125 
    THEN 4
    WHEN credits >= 150 
    THEN 5
    WHEN credits >= 200 
    THEN 6
END)
```

Comment: According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442), you seem to be trying to edit the same table in the trigger

Comment: Can you show us the trigger you tried to create and gave you an error?

Comment: _Help us to help you_ Show us what you have tried and someone will suggest a correction to the code or better way of doing it. But **it does not work** is no help at all.

Comment: You could create a constraint with case statement in SQL server,but i am not sure of syntax in mysql

Comment: @TheGameiswar Do you mean SQLServer or MYSQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly:SQL Server

Comment: @TheGameiswar OP has tagged `MYSQL` and `phpMyAdmin` so I dont see how that comment is relevant

Comment: just giving some idea on if this can be implemented or it can be done too

Comment: For this scenario, why have both Badge and credit in same table, if your badges depend on a range of credits for example 100-200 = advanced. then why not separate out, I know its not directly answering the question, but just as a thought.

Comment: any help you guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **virtual** Columns in MySQL/MariaDB. they can calculate. If you want to search over the new field you can use a persitent field.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` int(11) AS (a mod 10) VIRTUAL,
  `d` varchar(5) AS (left(b,5)) PERSISTENT
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

see Manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/