# (MySQL) Can't update table 'PARTS' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger, mysql-error-1442

I want the amount to be updated if the entry is in the table else a new one inserts.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER t 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PARTS
for each row

BEGIN
  if exists (SELECT Part_name FROM PARTS where part_name = new.part_name) then
      UPDATE PARTS SET amount=amount+NEW.amount WHERE 
      Part_name=NEW.Part_name;
   end if;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

When I'm trying:

```
mysql> insert into PARTS(Part_name,amount,Storage_ID) values('barley',1000,1);
```

Then I got this error:

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'PARTS' in stored 
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

What is my fault? Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger cannot update table - getting ERROR 1442](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442)

Comment: A trigger can't modify the the data which caused the trigger. The error is fairly clear about that.

Comment: Yes this is already an error. But point is the How can I do that? Any idea for this issue?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a trigger.  You want `insert on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into PARTS(Part_name, amount, Storage_ID)
    values('barley', 1000, 1)
    on duplicate key update amount = amount + values(amount);
```

For this to work, you need a unique index or primary key on `parts(part_name)`.  Or perhaps on `parts(part_name, storage_id)`.  It is unclear how that fits in.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand "For this to work, you need a unique index or primary key on parts(part_name). Or perhaps on parts(part_name, storage_id). It is unclear how that fits in." Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @K.tas . . . Are the `part_name`s unique?  Or are the `part_name`/`storage_id` pairs unique?