# Trigger updating a table after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

```
CREATE TRIGGER generate_cost
    AFTER INSERT on order_products FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET @cost = (select price from products where products.id = NEW.product_id);
        UPDATE order_products set order_products.cost = @cost * NEW.quantity;
END;
```

I do need to generate dynamically cost of order_items as taking price from product and multiplying it by client quantity input however it doesn't work - what should I do

It says - #1442 - Can't update table 'order_products' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Trigger cannot update table - getting ERROR 1442](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203859/mysql-trigger-cannot-update-table-getting-error-1442)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a value in the table the trigger is defined on, use a `before insert` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER generate_cost
    BEFORE INSERT on order_products
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select new.cost := p.price * new.quantity
    from products p
    where p.id = NEW.product_id;
END;
```